# iterate array to add values to slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works, but if the array is big, is annoying put all keys `$arr[0]`, `$arr[1]`, and so on.

```
$arr = shuffleArray(photos);

$.slideshow('slideshow', {
    backgrounds: [{
        src: $arr[0]
      }, {
        src: $arr[1]
      }
    ]
  })
```

So, i need something like this, but there is something wrong because the slideshow stops working and JS console is empty.

```
function slideshow() {
  $arr = shuffleArray(photos);
  $.slideshow('slideshow', {
      backgrounds: [
        $.each($arr, function (key, value) {
            {
              src: value
            }
          })
      ]
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to transform an array from one format to another

```
$arr = shuffleArray(photos);
var $srcs = $.map($arr, function(val, index){
    return {
        src: val
    }
})

$.slideshow('slideshow', {
    backgrounds: $srcs
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
backgrounds: [
        $.each($arr, function (key, value) {
            {
              src: value
            }
          })
      ]
```

**expects an array of objects**

So you need to wrap it up in a function that returns the value in that format.

```
$arr = shuffleArray(photos);

$.slideshow('slideshow', {
    backgrounds: (function () {
        var temp = [];
        $.each($arr, function (key, value) {
            temp.push({
                src: value
            });
        });
        return temp;
    })()
})
```

**[Check Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WNamL/)**